# function of difference between value

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x

Is there a function in Python to get the difference between two or more values in a list? So, in those two lists:

```
list1 = [1, 5, 3, 7]
list2 = [4, 2, 6, 4]
```

I need to calculate the difference between every value in list1 and list2.

```
for i in list1:
    for ii in list2:
       print i -ii
```

This gives negative values, but I want the subtraction between the values of the two lists only from highest value to lowest value for not getting negative values.

For the above lists, I expect the output to be `[3, 3, 3, 3]`.

Thanks.

Comment: show your attempts as well as the expected output...

Comment: Are you expecting `[3, 3, 3, 3]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may also do if else condition inside list comprehension.

```
>>> [i-j if i>j else j-i for i,j in zip(list1, list2)]
[3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: This is the same as `[abs(i-j) for i,j in zip(list1, list2)]`

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you expect `[3, 3, 3, 3]` as the answer in your question, you can use `abs` and `zip`:

```
[abs(i-j) for i,j in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 8):

Either `zip` the lists, or use `numpy`:

```
>>> list1 = [1, 5, 3, 7]
>>> list2 = [4, 2, 6, 4]
>>> [a-b for a,b in zip(list1, list2)]
[-3, 3, -3, 3]
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array(list1) - np.array(list2)
array([-3,  3, -3,  3])
```

Remember to cast the array back to a list as needed.

## **edit:**

In response to the new requirement that the absolute values are needed: you can add `abs` in the list comprehension:

```
>>> [abs(a-b) for a,b in zip(list1, list2)]
[3, 3, 3, 3]
```

and the `numpy` solution would change to:

```
>>> map(abs, np.array(list1) - np.array(list2))
[3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Depending on what the questioner was asking for... this answer looks good.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what was asked for... otherwise I ask @gho to clarify ;)

Comment: @timgeb, I edited it, what about this: [a-b for a,b in zip(list1, list2) if a > b else b-a ]

Answer (score 2):

You can use zip method in order combine these two lists. See the tutorials for zip method https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

```
>>> list1 = [1, 5, 3, 7]
>>> list2 = [4, 2, 6, 4]
>>> [abs(x-y) for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
[3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: This is no different than several of the already provided answers.

Answer (score 1):

Avinash Raj's answer is correct, or alternatively, using map():

```
from operator import sub
C = map(sub, A, B)
```

Comment: This is not correct. OP wants *only positive elements* in the array.